# Launch forms in a Dialog set to "No", but dialogs are still launching

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, dialog

I'm using Sharepoint Online, and in the advanced list settings I have "Launch forms in a dialog?" option set to no. However in the (Modern) list view it continues to open item details and editing in the slide out modal.

How/Can I force item details to redirect to a page instead of opening a model in the modern list view?

Answer (score 1):

It is by design.

Currently, the "Launch forms in a dialog?" only controls the classic list.

For the modern list, it is designed to edit item details in the information panel without leaving the list. when we new/edit an item, it will show a panel that slides out on the right.

Information about [modern list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/).

Comment: So is it possible to override this feature with JavaScript?

Comment: Currently, we cannot use JavaScript in a modern list view. You may need to use SPFx. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT Hi! I have a side question about this. How about when using a modern list (preview) web part. I added the web part on a communication site and it shows the list like it should but when I try to click the list items or add new ones, it takes me to a new page instead of using the side panel. So is it possible to use the side panel with the modern list (preview) web part also? :)

Comment: Two years later and it is still not possible to use the side panel in webparts. Very disappointing!

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT Are there any news or updates regarding plans on enabling the side panel for list web part?

Comment: @krombi have you found any workarounds or custom solutions to achieve this or something close to it?